# FULL_SCREEN with keyboard keyin

Tags: flash, fullscreen

Below is the Full screen mode when a button is clicked.
It works well in my local computer. In a webpage the HTML set Fullscreen= true and full screen works well but the keyboard do not work to keyin in the textbox.
Do I left anything to set in the HTML?

```
fullScreen_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fullscr);
function fullscr (e:MouseEvent):void {  

    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
    stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide allowFullScreenInteractive parameter for the OBJECT tag which embeds your Flash file:

```
<object ...> 
<param name="allowFullScreenInteractive" value="true" /> 
...
</object>
```

There is more info in the Adobe help: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS58a13becbbb904c7-28cf6d32136e60de784-8000.html